# R DBI: Check open connections

Tags: r, mysql-connector

I am using DBI package in R to retrieve data from MySQL database and work with them later. I have set up two connections to two databases using `dbConnect()` method. I've run the whole script several times and now received error message *Cannot allocate a new connection: 16 connections already opened*.

It surprised me because in the environment I can see only two connection classes and I thought they simply overwrite each time I run the script.

My questions are:

1. How can I check all the connections that are open (Found out that there is a `dbListConnections()` method but don't know what to pass as an argument)?
2. How do I close all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Assuming you are using RMySQL or RMariaDB

```
library(DBI)
```

###### Replace RMySQL with RMariaDB if that's what you're using

```
library(RMySQL)
```

###### Create a driver object

```
my_driver <- dbDriver("MySQL")
```

###### List all connections

```
all_connections <- dbListConnections(my_driver)
```

###### Close all connections

```
for(conn in all_connections) {
    dbDisconnect(conn)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read `?dbListConnections`, it is deprecated (has been [since Dec 2021](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/blame/main/R/dbListConnections.R)), so even if it is implemented by a driver (no idea), there's no guarantee it'll be maintained.

(*Edit*: it appears it is supported by `RMySQL`, since `DBI::dbListConnections(RMySQL::MySQL())` returns a `list()` (empty for me), but `DBI::dbListConnections(RMariaDB::MariaDB())` fails, suggesting it has not been ported to that package.)

To find everything in the local (typically *global* when interactive) environment, you can use this hack. I tend to connect to SQL Server, so my connections are classed as

```r
class(con)
# [1] "Microsoft SQL Server"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "odbc"
```

so I can find existing connections with

```r
conns <- sapply(mget(ls()), inherits, "Microsoft SQL Server")
conns <- names(conns[conns])
conns
# [1] "con"
```

With this, one can loop over them with something like:

```r
for (obj in conns) {
  DBI::dbDisconnect(get(obj))
  rm(list=obj)
}
```

NOTES:

- Generally you should not need to force-close all objects, just `rm()`-ing them will eventually allow them to "garbage-collect", which should close the connection automatically. This means we don't technically need the `dbDisconnect` line, but you'd still need to `rm(.)` the ones you want to be (eventually) garbage collected.
- Garbage collection is an odd thing ... you cannot always rely on it being done in a timely basis, especially while you are actively using R and keeping it "busy". Even if you run `rm(con)` and wait 10 seconds, it may not garbage collect. I don't know the time between `gc()`s, and especially if you're looking to (say) shut down the computer immediately, the above hack may still be necessary (or at least desired).

If you *can* (and choose to) use `dbListConnections` as my second paragraph suggests, then you can use this:

```r
for (obj in DBI::dbListConnections(RMySQL::MySQL())) {
  DBI::dbDisconnect(obj)
}
```

though I don't know offhand how to automatically remove the object as well.